# can i launch an Azure instance from openstack?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, openstack, hybrid

Openstack already contains API for EC2 integration but when I try to integrate with Azure, then i face various problems such as for VPN access i need to have physical routers and using an external domain as a DNS server is not an option. With AWS, the identity and access management service helps user to remotely integrate their instances with open cloud but there is no such facility available in Azure. Can anybody help me to find a way to integrate my openstack console with Azure?

Comment: You might want to take look at https://github.com/openstack/omni